# How to ignore unwanted characters from textbox (JavaScript or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's a TextBox that I wanna allow users to just enter numbers & not any alphabetical characters.
So how could I ignore those chars entered by end user via JavaScript or jQuery?
Notice I don't wanna replace user's entered value by empty string; Instead wanna ignore case if there is any way for it.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You want to restrict the user input to just numeric values and you want to ignore 'those chars' as entered and you don't want to replace entered value with an empty string (not sure where we are in your process here) and ignore case (of digits!?). Can you re-read your question and please revise it with examples of what you think might be input, how you want to process it and how you want to represent erroneous input to the user.

Comment: Bits of misunderstanding... I wanna restrict user input to just numeric values & if he entered any non-numeric chars, automatically ignore it; Means that specific char not to set all the input to empty string...

Comment: Edit your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try that code:

```
$("#id").keypress(function (e) {
    //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
    if ( e.which!=8 && e.which!=0 && (e.which<48 || e.which>57)) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

reference http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/04/textbox-accept-only-numbers-digits.html

Answer (score 1):

You want to attach a handler to the textbox's `keypress` event. In here check the `event.which` property to find out what key is pressed, and if it's not a number (between keycodes 48 and 57) return false, which will cancel the default behaviour of typing in the textbox.

```
$("input").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend intercepting keystrokes, allow the user to type whatever he/she wants, and validate on user action (submit/select etc).

Look at this jQuery plugin for instance: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Do they "need" it or "want" it? :-) Often they think they know what they "need", but it turns out to be a "want". Anyways, great if you found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

you said you didn't want to include alphabetical then you said you just want to ignore case? what do you need to do?

You can ignore lower case in JS by using `string.toLowerCase()`

Comment: That doesn't so much ignore lower case as force all alphabetic characters to lower case (one might say making it all the more important and certainly not ignored). That said, forcing both sides of a string comparison to lower (or upper) case is one way of implementing a case insensitive comparison.

Comment: By "case" I mean user's entered text

Comment: ah yes, well i mean ignore uppercase by setting all to lower case. but you are right, its for case-insensitive comparisons

Comment: Case means entered text now?

Answer (score 0):

For numeric-only I use this jQuery extension/plug in

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

Answer (score 0):

In above options we can prevent the user from keyboard, but what if the user paste something, it will not restrict user to not paste any special character.

For example we are restricting it from keyboard with proper error msg

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#package").keypress(function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

            $("#lblError").html("");

            //Regex for Valid Characters i.e. Alphabets and Numbers.
            var regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;

            //Validate TextBox value against the Regex.
            var isValid = regex.test(String.fromCharCode(keyCode));
            if (!isValid) {
                $("#lblError").html("Only Alphabets and Numbers allowed.");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#lblError").html("");
            }

            return isValid;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now let's prevent it from pasting special character.

```
$('#package').bind("paste",function(){  
   var data= $('#package').val() ;
   var removedNotAllowed = data.replace(/[^ws]/gi, '');
   $( '#package' ).val(removedNotAllowed);
   $("#lblError").html("Only Alphabets and Numbers allowed.");
});
```