# How to use Javascript to filter and ignore keypresses on an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dojo

I need to stop accepting input (keystrokes) on an HTML form input field when the length limit has been reached.   In straight-up HTML I can do this with `maxlength="3"` or whatever the length is, but I would like to handle it through Javascript if possible so I can do it together with the next requirement.

I also need to filter the input so that if a field is numeric only numbers can be typed, and if there's a mask or regex any inputs conform to the mask/regex.

Is there a "standard" way to do this in, Javascript, particularly in Dojo 1.9?  (I know everybody uses JQuery but we use Dojo because.)

Comment: This may be what you're looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450056/how-to-ignore-unwanted-characters-from-textbox-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dojo, if you need any sort of validation, I would use the ValidationTextBox, which takes "maxLength" as a property AND allows for all sorts of nifty validation schemes. The reference for ValidationTextBox is here:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/ValidationTextBox.html

Comment: This looks like the best solution involving Dojo.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used [pure Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/bLJb8/2/) because I am not familiar with Dojo, but these event listeners can probably be cleaned up with Dojo.

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
    error = document.getElementById('error');

input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
        e.preventDefault();
        error.innerHTML = 'Must be a digit';
    } else if(e.target.value.length >= 3) {
        e.preventDefault();
        error.innerHTML = 'Cannot be more than 3 digits';        
    } else {
        error.innerHTML = '';
    }
});
```

We listen to a keypress and then, to make sure it is a digit, we seek that the key pressed was between 48-57 (0-9).  If not, then we prevent the key press and show an error.  Then we check the input's current length.  If it is too long, then prevent the key press and show an error.  Otherwise, it worked and we allow the event and clear the error.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe looking for this:

```
<input id="text" type="text"/>

$('#text').on('keypress',function(e){
    var numero  = this.value.length;

    console.log(this.value.length);
  if (e.which != 8 && e.which < 48 ||  e.which > 57)
  {
      return false
  }
    else if (numero === 3 && e.which != 8){
     return false //alert user here
    }else{
        return true // allow backspace only (8)
    }
 }
);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ePJsd/7/)